# statement cannot begin with a closure statement on for loop

Tags: swift2, xcode7, swift-playground

I have strange issue in Xcode Playground, I have no idea if I had same problem before Xcode 7.

You can see left arrow (less than) position on for loop conditional section, 1st and 3rd syntax has problem and 2nd and 4th have correct syntax...

I am using Xcode 7 and same issue is on Project (not Playground).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift beginner mistake: Space around operators is significant. It's

```
a<b or a < b but not a <b or a< b.
```

Comment: Earlier i had gone through same issues, later i came to known  the same as @gnasher

Comment: if space around operators is significant , then a<b should not be valid too.seems some hard rule by swift. and swift is not like python that counts space.

Comment: Read the Swift book. No spaces at all or spaces on both sides = binary operator. Space on the left side = prefix unary operator. Space on the right side = postfix unary operator.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem of space around operators would be to use the "swiftier" way of looping:

```
for item in array {
    // do something with item
}
```

Same with an index:

```
for (index, item) in array.enumerate() {
    // do something with index and item
}
```

There's also `map` to get a modified array from another array:

```
let result = array.map { item in
    // apply transformation to `item`
}
```

There's no need to continue using the old `for var i = 0; ...` mechanism anymore in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This thread seems to indicate this is a bug. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6775

Comment: this problem is on Project too not only on playground

Comment: Unfortunately. I'm not an expert on this. I was just trying to help you find some other answers. I guess your project could be configured in the wrong way?